# Adding Transparent Circle to background images

Tags: java, image, swing, awt, java-2d

I need to make a drum instrument. I already have a background images and sound. Now I need to add 4 transparent circle to the drum to produced 4 different sound.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PictureOnClickOneSound 
{

  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {
    // Create a "clickable" image icon.
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\apr13mpsip\\Pictures\\Drum2.jpg");
    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
    label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
    {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) 
      {
        sound1.Sound1.play();
        System.out.println("CLICKED");
      }
    }); 

    // Add it to a frame.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Window");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/), in particular [Compositing Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html)

Comment: if the circle is transparent how will the user know where to click? Does the user just click randomly and hope for the best? Does your image have 4 drums and you are trying to overly the circles on each drum?

Comment: Yes my image has 4 drums. And i want to place the 4 cirlce on the 4 drums

Comment: 1) This has nothing to do with Eclipse (I.E. you do it the exact same way in Eclipse as in Netbeans or TextPad) 2) You should edit [your original post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17390982/418556) rather than start a new one.

Comment: BTW - You might link to the (preferably small) image, so that like in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556) people can experiment.  A picture paints a thousand words.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Create a Map that contains a Shape to represent a location on your image along with the Sound file to play when that location is clicked. Something like:

```
Map<Shape, Sound> shapes = new Hashmap<Shape, Sound>();

shapes.put(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 50, 50), soundFile1);
shapes.put(new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 50, 50, 50), soundFile2);
```

Then in the mouseClicked() event you need to search the map to see if the mouse was clicked in any of your shapes. Something like:

```
for (Shape shape: shapes.keySet())
{
    if (shape.contains(event.getPoint());
    {
        Sound sound = shapes.get(shape);
        sound.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you dont mind. Can you show me where to put the sample code into

Comment: I showed you which code goes into the mouse listener. The other code doesn't go into the mouse listener. The code is not exact because I don't know how you play your music. The code I showed you is a concept because you will also need to determine the appropriate shape locations based on your image.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to add '*transparent circles*', just use the properties [getX()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getX%28%29) and [getY()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getY%28%29) of the `MouseEvent` to identify the position it was clicked in the image and then play the relative sound to it.

For each circle, store the x, y center position and the radius.

```
public class Circle{
   double xCenter;
   double yCenter;
   double radius;
}
```

When the MouseEvent action is performed, iterate through the circles and check if the click was inside of any:

```
for(Circle c : circles){
   //check if the click was inside this circle
   if (Math.sqrt((c.xCenter-mouseEvent.getX())^2+(c.yCenter-mouseEvent.getY())^2) <= c.radius) {
      //play sound for c
   }
}
```

Comment: if you dont mind. Can you tell me where to insert the sample that you give based on my code.

Comment: the for loop need to be inserted in the mouseClicked method, but you need to create the instance of the circles based in their x, y location in the image